# Laravel 5.2 - Getting a pivot table additional attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel to track Gear in Wearhouses. For that I have 2 tables: gears and wearhouses, and another pivot table: gear_wearhouse.

The relationship between the two tables is a many-to-many relationship, and in my pivot table, in addition to the gear_id and wearhouse_id columns, I have a `qty` (quantity) column.

Now I loaded all the wearhouses that store a certain gear item (`$whs = $gear->wearhouses`), and I want to get the quantity (`qty` field) from the pivot table.

Here is my code:

```
@foreach ($gear->wearhouses as $wh)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $wh->title }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $wh->manager->name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $wh->pivot->qty }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ url('/admin/organization/gear/edit/' . $wh->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> עריכה
            </a>

            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#delete-{{ $wh->id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> מחיקה
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

`$wh->pivot->qty` returns nothing.

How can I do that the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$warehouse = Warehouse::find(1);
$gears = $warehouse->gears;
foreach($gears as $gear)
{
   $qty = $gear->pivot->qty;
}
```

or

```
$warehouse = Warehouse::find(1);
$gear = $warehouse->gears()->first();
$qty = $gear->pivot->qty;
```

Comment: I added my code to the question. Please take a look, it doesn't work.

Comment: can u please provide screenshot for output : dd($wh->pivot);

Comment: My bad (for the previews comment which I deleted) - still not working.

Comment: can u provide screenshot for output dd($wh) and code in models Wearhouse and Gear